# data type with both alphabets and integers in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have data frame with the column 'Item'. When I run this query:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SKUIDs': fullFrame.Item})
bySKU = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['SKUIDs']).size(),columns = ['Lines'])
```

the results are like this:

[image]

How can I get this:

[image]

Comment: 1st replace white blank to '' in SKUIDs, then do you code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fullFrame.Item.str.strip().value_counts().to_frame('Lines')
```

Comment: Here you go ~ :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have whitespaces in the values of the SKUIDs column, do the following

```
bySKU['SKUIDs'] = bySKU['SKUIDs'].str.strip()  
bySKU = bySKU.groupby('SKUIDs', as_index=False).agg({'Lines':'sum'})
```

---

You can also proceed as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SKUIDs': fullFrame.Item})
bySKU['SKUIDs'] = bySKU['SKUIDs'].str.strip() 
bySKU = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['SKUIDs']).size(),columns = ['Lines'])
```

Comment: I added this line and solved: fullFrame['Item'] = fullFrame['Item'].str.strip()